# RestAssured: Url Constrcution with query param where param value is not String

Tags: api-testing, rest-assured

Is there a way to construct Url with query parameters where the **value of the query param is not string**. For String values of query parameter there are APIs in RestAssured or apache httpClient but I could not find any such API matching my needs.

e.g. Query param is:

```
        Map queryParam = ImmutableMap.of("activityTypeList", Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
```

For String valued query parameters, I am following the below approach:

```
    public String urlBuilder(String url, Map<String, String> queryParam) throws URISyntaxException{
        URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(url);
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry: queryParam.entrySet()){
            uriBuilder.addParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        return uriBuilder.toString();
    }
```

I understand this can be achieved by:

```
request.queryParam("activityTypeList", Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
```

where `request` is an object of type `RequestSpecification`. I am more interested in the URL construction approach.

> A followup question: Is there an API which provides the URL that the
>   RestAssured client hits after URL construction; would be much helpful
>   for logging.

Any lead in RestAssured/httpClient/okHttp would really help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, your code fails because

```
 public String urlBuilder(String url, Map<String, String> queryParam)
```

In the parameter definition, you type casts it as a Map of `Map<String, String>` and then you are passing a map of `Map<String, ArrayList>`

So just changing that will fix the issue:

```
public String urlBuilder(String url, Map<String, Object> queryParam) throws URISyntaxException{
        URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(url);
        for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry: queryParam.entrySet()){

            System.out.println(entry.getValue());
            uriBuilder.addParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString());
        }
        return uriBuilder.toString();
    }
```

More cleaner code:

```
ImmutableMap<String, List<Integer>> queryParam = ImmutableMap.of("activityTypeList", Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
```

and

```
public String urlBuilder(String url, Map<String, List<Integer>> queryParam) throws URISyntaxException{
        URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(url);
        for(Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry: queryParam.entrySet()){

            System.out.println(entry.getValue());
            uriBuilder.addParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString());
        }
        return uriBuilder.toString();
    }
```

You can achieve logging by using:

```
 RestAssured.given().
 filter(new RequestLoggingFilter()).
 filter(new ResponseLoggingFilter()).
 when().get("/user");
```

If you want to redirect it to a print stream then:

```
     StringWriter requestwrite = new StringWriter();
 PrintStream  requestcapture = new PrintStream(new WriterOutputStream(requestwrite),true);

 StringWriter reswrite = new StringWriter();
 PrintStream  rescapture = new PrintStream(new WriterOutputStream(reswrite),true);


 RestAssured.given().
 filter(new RequestLoggingFilter(requestcapture)).
 filter(new ResponseLoggingFilter(rescapture)).
 when().get("/user");


 System.err.println(requestwrite.toString());
 System.err.println(reswrite.toString());
```